# If cosmological redshift causes wavelength elongation does it mean the whole emitted signal is elongated?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, cosmology, time-dilation, redshift

If cosmological redshift causes wavelength elongation does it mean the whole emitted signal is elongated? Let say we have ten waves on the see hitting the shore.... If we somehow elongate every single wave by a factor of 10 the whole series of them will also be streched by that factor and its collision with the shore will last longer than before elongation. Is this the same in case of EM waves emitted from deep space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For example the light from a distant supernova is redshifted and the rise and fall duration of the supernova is dilated by the same factor.